# Make a request with an "consumer token" with oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using [intridea/oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) for oauth2 functionality. Everything is working fine with authentication and making requests with an access token.

But what i can not find out is how to make a request without an access token. I thought it would simply work with

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(key, secret, :site => site)
client.request(:post, "/api/users", {params: {param1: "val1"}})
```

but that does not seem to work. It is not setting any oauth header in the request.

How do i make a request like that?

Comment: For what reason do you want to leave out the access token?

Comment: There are some requests which are not bound to a user. So i want to secure some calls that are just concerning the application without any user involved.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out oAuth completely then. Use simple `Net::HTTP` requests or use a library like [REST Client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) for example.

Comment: I do not want to add an additional layer. I at least want to secure it. Other libraries, like e.g. [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) support such kinds of access. There you just have to use OAuthConstants.EMPTY_TOKEN in order to make such a call.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the library isn't capable of something like that. So i now have two ways of authentication. You can find some information on this page: http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast